# How to print a pdf file using flutter with web platform?

Tags: flutter, printing, flutter-web

I want to print a pdf file using flutter web app.
I'm working with flutter app which is required to print pdf using web platform, are there any solution to do that? I've tried to find solution several days, but nothing found. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check out this https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/ and use window.print() to print  a page